# In Pages on iPad, formatting to add line over paragraph?

Tags: pages, formatting, ipados

I’m writing a document with Pages on iPad. When I select the “Heading 3” style it puts a line above the text, like this:

[image]

I can't find how to create that kind of formatting manually, outside of the named styles. Where is the option? Here is the part of the screen with formatting controls. I don't see anything to create a border or line above a text block.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Select the header you wish to modify.
2. Then under Text>Font select the ellipsis […]
3. Add outline using toggle

[image: Screenshot showing text modify]
[image: Screenshot showing outline on header text]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't add/edit text line styles on i(Pad)OS.

You can edit text line styles in Pages for macOS (Format sidebar > Text > Layout), though, which then carry over/display in Pages for i(Pad)OS.